# Google sign-in for websites - Invalid Request error

Tags: google-signin, federated-identity

I am trying to follow the tutorial for [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) . I have copied Google's example exactly, but when I press the sign-in button, an "Invalid Request" error is reported.

The Url for my page is ...

- https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22/index.html

The content of this page is ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="230599269648-86peetl434op89ug41lg1vv8sjspfupp.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>


</head>

<body>
Content of the document......
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>   
    </body>

</html>
```

The web application is properly registered with the Google Developer's Console. Here is the registration downloaded in a json format ...

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "230599269648-86peetl434op89ug41lg1vv8sjspfupp.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "test-federated-login-196400",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": (redacted),
        "javascript_origins": [
            "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

When a user presses the sign-in button, the pop-up dialog reports a 400 error with text ...

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: invalid_request
Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.
```

... with request details ...

```
redirect_uri=storagerelay://https/s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com?id=auth370793
response_type=permission id_token
scope=email profile openid
openid.realm=
client_id=230599269648-86peetl434op89ug41lg1vv8sjspfupp.apps.googleusercontent.com
ss_domain=https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
fetch_basic_profile=true
gsiwebsdk=2
```

**How do I get this basic example of Google Sign-in on a web page to work?**

Answer (score 0):

I have a work-around. I cannot explain why it works and the OP solution does not.

AWS bucket objects have two different URL formats:

1. https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22
2. http://sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

I've used Google's webmaster Central to claim ownership and to verify ownership of two domains:

1. https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22/
2. http://sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/

Although of course, I cannot claim https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

The first form of URL is generally intended for use in API's. The second is intended for use in the browser (although in the second form, only http is allowed, not https).

I've then modified the javascript origins to add the second form ...

{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "230599269648-86peetl434op89ug41lg1vv8sjspfupp.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "test-federated-login-196400",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": (redacted),
        "javascript_origins": [
            "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",
            "http://sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
    }
}

... and then addressing the page in the browser by the second form ...

- http://sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

... I can then sign-in.

I can't sign-out. The sign0out button raises javascript errors, but that is another question for another day.

### Morale of the story

When implementing Google Sign-In on an Amazon AWS hosted bucket ...

1. Use the website hosting form of the url (http://bucket-name.s3-website-region-amazonaws.com)
2. Claim and verify ownership of the domain in Webmaster central (in the website hosting form)
3. Use the same url in javascript origins
4. Don't use the API form of the bucket url.